# Wrong html table rendering using colspan and rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>first table </p>
<table>
    <tr> <td rowspan="3">B</td> <td rowspan="2">C</td> <td rowspan="1">D</td></tr>
    <tr> <td rowspan="1">E</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>F</td> <td>G</td> </tr>
</table>
<p> second table, seems to wrong renden</p>
<table>
    <tr> <td rowspan="3">B</td> <td rowspan="2">C</td> <td rowspan="1">D</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td rowspan="2">E</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>F</td> </tr>
</table>
```

In my opinion the second table should look like the first table, except
that the cells E and G should be joined to a rowspan 2 cell E.

But in doesn't, it just seems to have 2 rows and not 3, why?

Answer (score 2):

If you give fixed height to each row then you can observe the difference. It is rendering properly. I think it is happening because of auto adjustment of the height of the rows. I have included fixed height style in your code. Observe the difference.

```css
table {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}

tr{
  height:20px
}
```

```html
<p>first table </p>
<table>
    <tr> <td rowspan="3">B</td> <td rowspan="2">C</td> <td rowspan="1">D</td></tr>
    <tr> <td rowspan="1">E</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>F</td> <td>G</td> </tr>
</table>
<p> second table, seems to wrong renden</p>
<table>
    <tr> <td rowspan="3">B</td> <td rowspan="2">C</td> <td rowspan="1">D</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td rowspan="2">E</td> </tr>
    <tr> <td>F</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

understand, in my original example the height of the second row was just 0 ...